# Convert Blob to File in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, javascript-objects

I've been reading about `Blobs` and `Files` for a while and I've read that the `File` interface is based on `Blob`.

My problem is that I need to send a `File` object to a server, which reads the file's data through the `filedata` property - that I assume is present on `File` objects.

This is what I have:

```
RNFS.readFile(path, 'base64')
    .then((result) => {
       console.log('GOT RESULT', result);
       var file = new File([result], filename, {
              type: doc.file.type,
              lastModified: new Date().getTime(),
           });
    });
```

However, that isn't creating a `File` object, but a `Blob`, and I assume that because of the `__proto__` value. It is returning something like:

```
_data:
    blobId: "6a3af6ba-f89c-4f43-8fa8-9da24782b722"
    lastModified: 1627313885570
    name: "filename.png"
    offset: 0
    size: 224156
    type: "image/png"
__collector: null
__proto__: Object
data: (...)
lastModified: (...)
name: (...)
size: (...)
type: (...)
__proto__: Blob
```

Is there any way to effectively create a `File` object in React Native?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you got any solutiion?

Comment: Any solution so far?